# Create query in QueryEditor with VBA function call for specifying the WHERE IN clause

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have written a couple of VBA functions which in the end return a Collection of Integers:

```
Public Function ValidIDs() As Collection
```

Now I want to run create a query in the QueryEditor with the following condition: `WHERE TableID IN ValidIDs()`. That does not work since access for some reason does not even find my function as long as it returns a Collection. Therefore I wrote a wrapper around it, which joins the Collection:

```
Public Function joinCollectionForIn(Coll As Collection) As String
```

Now a third function which calls `ValidIDs()`, passes the result to `joinCollectionForIn` and returns that result. Lets call it `GetIDCollectionAsString()`.

As a result I can now change my query to `WHERE TableID IN (GetIDCollectionAsString())`. Note the added parenthesis since the `IN` needs them in any case, they can not just be at the end and the beginning of the String returned by `GetID...`.

Running that query however results in

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

I guess that results from the fact that I return a String, therefore access automatically wraps that string in `'` for the SQL and the `IN`-clause no longer works because I would check if a number is `IN` a collection of 1 string.

Therefore my question is:

- Is there a way to prevent access from wrapping the returned string for the SQL

or (would be a whole lot better):

- Is there an already existing way to pass a collection or array to the `WHERE IN`-clause?

**P.S.**: I am currently using a workaround by writing a placeholder in the parenthesis following the `IN` (e.g. `IN (1,2,3,4,5)`) and replacing that placeholder in Form_Load with the result of `GetIDCollectionAsString()` - that works but it is not pretty...

**Edit**: The final query should look like `SELECT * FROM TestTable t WHERE t.ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)`. That actually works using above method, but not in a nice way.

Comment: can you show an example of what you get from the function `GetIDCollectionAsString`..Also take note that the `IN` clause for strings wants this kind of input `IN ('Id01','Id02'.....)`

Comment: It returns something like "1, 2, 3, 4, 5" which is exactly what I want. They are not supposed to be wrapped in `'` because they are supposed to be integers.

Comment: As far as I can remember, Access does not support this. Having an IN clause generated RUN TIME. You can however use VBA.

Comment: @PaulFrancis With "You can however use VBA" you mean something along my P.S.? Creating or altering the query using vba instead of building it entirely in the Query Editor!?

Comment: Yes, did not really get what you meant by `writing a placeholder`, now it makes more sense. Unfortunately, AFAIK - that is the way to go.

Comment: Hmpf, i am getting the feeling that slowly but surely i am exceeding the regular use cases for access :/

Comment: After a fair bit of searching it seems like the answer is that you can't do what you want and that you will just need to build the query dynamically within VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Well this required more work than it seems.... i couldn't find a straight solution so here is a workaround

```
Public Function ListforIn(inputString As String) As String
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Dim valCriteria As String
    Dim strsql As String
    Dim splitcounter As Byte
    Dim valcounter As Byte

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(**TheNameOfQueryYouWantToModify**)

    strsql = qdf.sql
    strsql = Replace(strsql, ";", "") 'To get rid of ";"
    splitcounter = Len(inputString) - Len(Replace(inputString, ",", ""))

    For valcounter = 0 To splitcounter
        valCriteria = valCriteria & ValParseText(inputString, valcounter, ",")
    Next

    strsql = strsql & " WHERE TableId IN (" & Left(valCriteria, Len(valCriteria) - 1) & ")"
    qdf.sql = strsql
End Function


Public Function ValParseText(TextIn As String, X As Byte, Optional MyDelim As String) As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    If Len(MyDelim) > 0 Then
        ValParseText = "Val(" & (Split(TextIn, MyDelim)(X)) & "),"
    Else
        ValParseText = Split(TextIn, " ")(X)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: That would only retrieve the first number of all my returned numbers since it `stops reading the string at the first character it can't recognize as part of a number`

Comment: if you get a string like `"1,2,3,4,5"` and you put the val then it works ....i am missing something ? ....`IN(val("1,2,3,4,5"))`

Comment: `IN(val("1,2,3,4,5"))` will become `IN(1)` - not what I want

Comment: I just saw it...you are right...i will try and find a solution

Comment: Thanks, i will try to come up with one as well ;)

Comment: given the fact that your IN clause is feeded from function i guess one solution is to change the output of the GetIDCollectionAsString to output `"Val(id1),val("id2"),val("id3")....,` it will not be the most elegant but will do the job

Comment: I highly doubt that works, the return of my method would still be string and access would still wrap that string - i think it would not even execute the `Val(...)` because it is just a string, not a function call anymore.

Comment: can u share the function you use.. i want to try it...to check the output

Comment: Has nothing to do with my function, just create a function that returns two integers seperated by a comma and create a testquery and check if that query returns the two rows with those IDs or none or just the first one: `Public Function TestCollection() As String
    TestCollection = "1,2,3"
End Function`

Comment: I thank you for your effort! The posted code however would just revert my already existing code to join a collection into a string - it will result in pretty much the exact same situation as putlined in my P.S. while doing even more unneccesary work than I am currently doing :/

Comment: as it is is surely more work but 1st.it works....i have test it and 2nd. you should take the elements you need and insert them to your code

Comment: You can view my current workaround [here](http://pastebin.com/h7qY446D) and see that is in fact a lot cleaner.

Comment: well its cleaner but you use  predefined criteria....no problem ,if my solution is not what you want then forget it.